# Delaying File Download

Tags: php, download

I have looked around and I couldn't find an answer to this so I thought I'd ask.

Most file sharing sites allow premium users to download without a delay to the download link and they can download the file at normal speed. Normal users and guests however have to wait 60 seconds to get to the download link, and when they do get the download link, the file downloads incredibly slow.

> Download file 201503201242.mp4 (270.50 MB)
>   Download time: 1 hour, with Premium: 55 sec.

That's an example of what I see on one of them.

Just out of curiosity, how does one slow down a file download, in say, PHP?

Comment: A lot of examples : https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php+reduce+download+speed

Comment: @zeflex Well I'm surprised I hadn't found that. "Limit" and "Reduce" are two words I hadn't tried. Cheers.